# Obtaining MmNonPagedPoolStart on x64 systems

Tags: windows, memory

On a x64 Windows 7 I want to get the limits of non paged pool. I know that _KDDEBUGGER_DATA64 structure has this information (fields like MmNonPagedPoolStart and MmNonPagedPoolEnd). 
On x86 systems this structure was obtained from KPCR.KdVersionBlock, but looking with WinDbg at KPCR's on x64 systems, KdVersionBlock seems to always be null.

Is there a way of getting this structure? Or another way of getting what I want? Maybe I'm not looking in the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nt!KdDebuggerDatablock` used to be a public global symbol in NT

```
lkd> x/v nt!KdDebuggerDataBlock
pub global 80545b60             0 nt!KdDebuggerDataBlock = <no type information>
```

`dpS  nt!KdDebuggerDataBlock lxxxx` should fetch the `NonPagedPoolStart`

```
lkd> !grep -i -c "dpS nt!KdDebuggerDataBlock la5" -e "pool"
 8055b5a0 nt!ExpPagedPoolDescriptor
 8054ab2c nt!ExpNumberOfPagedPools
 nt!MmMaximumNonPagedPoolInBytes
 80553cb8 nt!MmNonPagedPoolStart
```

This should get the complete structure

```
lkd> .printf "%ma\t%08x\n" , nt!KdDebuggerDataBlock+10,poi(nt!KdDebuggerDataBlock+14)
KDBG    00000290
lkd> .for (r $t0=0 ; @$t0 <poi(nt!KdDebuggerDataBlock + 14) ; r $t0 = @$t0+4) { .printf "%08x\t%08x\t%y\n", (nt!KdDebuggerDataBlock + @$t0) ,poi(nt!KdDebuggerDataBlock + @$t0) ,poi(nt!KdDebuggerDataBlock + @$t0) }
```